# How to set validation.yml for form with passwords (Symfony2)

Tags: php, validation, symfony

I would like to know how to check whether the entered by user passwords are the same? I need solution for validation.yml file. I have something like that:

**validation.yml:**

```
ZaqU\MyBundle\Entity\SignupForm:
    properties:
        password:
            - NotBlank:
                message: trans.validation.password.notBlank
            - Length:
                min: 8
                max: 30
                minMessage: trans.validation.password.minLength
                maxMessage: trans.validation.password.maxLength
        rpassword:
            - NotBlank:
                message: trans.validation.rpassword.notBlank
```

What I should add to rpassword from this list: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints.html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the form framework together with the validator, you can use the [repeated field type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/repeated.html).

If you want to use the validator alone, you can use one of these constraints:

- [Callback](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html)
- [Expression](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Expression.html)

You'll find the constraint reference here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints.html